# knock template binding after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates, knockout.js

I went through the knockout tutorial of binding data to a template using foreach and I got that to work.  I can make a successful ajax call to a controller and I see that the data is the same as the hardcoded data.  But I get nothing on the screen.  No errors in the javascript console.

My assumption is that I need to change the syntax around a little.  I've googled for a few hours but cannot find a good example.  Does anyone have a good example that uses an ajax call to populate a knockout template?

Here is my js code:

```
function RecordViewModel(url) {
    var self = this;
    self.cards = ko.observableArray();
    self.loadData = function () {
        $.get(url.load, function (data) {
            self.cards = data;
        });
    }
}

var vm = new RecordViewModel({
    load: '/records/getcards'
});

$(function () {
    vm.loadData();    
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

The html:

```
   <script type="text/html" id="record-template">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text:artist" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text:description" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3"><span data-bind="text:price"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </script>


<div data-bind="template: {name: 'record-template', foreach: cards() }"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know you rather set the value of an observable like this:

```
self.cards(data)
```

instead of

```
self.cards = data;
```